# OS X custom login authentication

Tags: macos, security, authentication, sfauthorizationpluginview

**My Requirement**
I need to authenticate the users at login with my own logic like, For eg: calling an external authentication server and using OpenDirectory in case if the server is not reachable.

**What I know**
I know that i need to create an authorization plugin like the apple's sample [NullAuthPlugin](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/NullAuthPlugin/Introduction/Intro.html) and add an entry in authorizationdb at 'system.login.console' right to invoke my plugin to achieve this.

**What I need**
Can I able to achieve my requirement **without replacing** the loginwindow GUI ie the mechanism `<string>loginwindow:login</string>`??
ie,Can i able to achieve this by keeping the existing mac's login screen as such and obtain the credentials to perform my own authentication ?? If possbile where should i place my mechanism at 'system.login.console' ?

**My idea**
I think of replacing the `<string>builtin:authenticate,privileged</string>` with my own plugin to achieve my requirement ? Is it OK to replace the buitin login mechanism ?

Is my approach correct ? Can anyone help me to clarify regarding this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understood you can create an authorizationplugin and put it after `<string> loginwindow: login </ string>`.

It will not replace the macOS auth but it will add a layer, I'm not sure what it will look like if you remove `<string> builtin: authenticate, privileged </ string>`, but I think I remember that I tried something like that and it was crashing.

Otherwise you can also write a PAM module, the PAM stack is just invoked on it: `<string> builtin: authenticate, privileged </ string>`
If you add a module with `sufficient` control flag on `/etc/pam.d/authorization` file it will do the job.

Comment: Thanks @Florian Z. I will look into it